# Postfix using gmail relay without a domain name gets dns error

Tags: server, dns, email, postfix, gmail

When I send mails using sendmail or mutt, `/var/log/mail.log` shows that emails get delivered to `smtp.gmail.com`. I can actually see the email appearing in my Gmail outbox. However, I receive an error message from my gmail inbox, as follows: [DNS Error: 4117387 DNS type 'mx' lookup of wallet-n550jv.localdomain responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: wallet-n550jv.localdomain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgtNH.png)
I am only using gmail as a relay to send email with my gmail account, do I still need to set up DNS record for that?
Here is my `postconf -n` output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
myhostname = wallet-N550JV.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $myhostname
notify_classes = policy
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd  can I ask if this is a hash of a password, or a password in plain text?

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` set:

```
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
relay_domains = gmail.com
```

then reload/restart postfix.

Comment: I made the change, but didn't seem to make a difference, I still get an email saying the same thing. (I included brackets around `smtp.gmail.com`. If I do `relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587` without bracket, I get a bounced status in the log file.)

Comment: Did you set relay_domains? Did you reload/restart Postfix?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I did: `relay_domains = gmail.com
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587`

Comment: Did you issue a reload for postfix to reread its config files? Or reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did a reload and restarted the service.